# problem with classes when scraping tripadvisor with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape tripadvisor reviews. I use the code

```
trip_ad <- read_html("http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g189400-d10798588-Reviews-Electra_Metropolis_Athens-Athens_Attica.html")

house <- trip_ad %>%
html_elements("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")
```

But it returns a list of 0.

The same is if I try

```
review <- trip_ad %>%
  html_elements(".XllAv H4 _a")
```

Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and lmk.

```
 review <- trip_ad %>%
        html_nodes(".XllAv H4 _a") %>%
        html_text()
```

Comment: It returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved in the way bellow

````
  read_html("home/tripad/file_saved_using_firefox.html") 

reviews4 <- reviews3 %>% 
  html_elements("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")```
````